# Count days within a month from date range

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have three date ranges in mysql table as follow

- from 2013-09-29 to 2013-10-02
- from 2013-10-14 to 2013-10-16
- from 2013-10-28 to 2013-11-05

I want to count only days that occur in Month of October, for example  from first range (2013-09-29 to 2013-10-02) I should get difference of two days (1st and 2nd October) , and it should ignore days from September month, Finally i want to count total days in a given month from above date ranges.

Can it be done from direct mysql query. or any short PHP logic.

here is my table structure 
id,employee_id,leave_start,leave_to

I am looking for a method some thing like

function countLeaves($employee_id,$month)
{

// code

return $numberOfLeaves
}

Comment: tell me exact value which u get from database...

Comment: Try to use `gregoriantojd` and subtract

Comment: Actually I want to count number of leaves of a employee within a month, So my method will look like this
`code`
function countLeaves($employeeId,$month)
{

//mysql query + php logic

return $numberOfDays;
}
`code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the first day of the month 2013-10-01 and the last day of the month 2013-10-31 and then you could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(
    LEAST(d_end, '2013-10-31'),
    GREATEST(d_start, '2013-10-01'))+1 days
FROM
  ranges
WHERE
  d_start<='2013-10-31' AND d_end>='2013-10-01'
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3421/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
$month = strtotime(date('Y-m-01', time()));
$daysCount = (int)(time() - $month) / (24 * 3600);
```

and if you need to check from any date to any date:

```
/**
* @var $dateFrom string Date to count from, 
* you can use date('Y-m-01') as start of current month
* @var $dateTo string End of period date, example: '2013-09-05'
**/
function getDaysCount($dateFrom, $dateTo)
{
    return (int)(strtotime($dateTo) - strtotime($dateFrom)) / (24 * 3600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function getAllDates($fromDate, $toDate,$rejectmonth)
    {
        if(!$fromDate || !$toDate ) {return false;}

```
    $dateMonthYearArr = array();
    $fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
    $toDateTS = strtotime($toDate);
    for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24))
    {

        if($rejectmonth == date("m",$currentDateTS))
            continue;
        $currentDateStr = date("Y-m-d",$currentDateTS);
        $dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;
    }
    return $dateMonthYearArr;
}
```

use this function will return the array dates which are in the date ranges.

getAllDates('2013-09-10','2013-19-10',10);