# PHP | count num of days for current month in a date range

Tags: php, date

i am trying to get dates of current month or any other month from a date range.

Let Suppose I have a Date Range as Below.

```
$startDate = "2014-12-10";
$endDate = "2015-2-3";
```

I want to count only days/dates of current month `"February"`
which would result in 3 if start date and end date is above one.

but how can i make it work in a programming manner??

-=-=-=-=-==-=

**update:**

I think i could not explain my question,

Lets Take the same date range..

if i want to programmatically take out days of December Month

it would be like

21 days, as start date is `2014-12-10`;

Dates Are in Range Coming Programmatically from database..

-=-==-=-=-=-=-=

**UPDATE 2:**

An other simple example

Lets Suppose If Leaves Have Been Approved For an Employee from `28-1-2015` to `6-2-2015`

so Here Employees Leaves Taken Start Date Would Be

```
$sartDate = '28-1-2015';
$endDate = '6-2-2015';
```

So Total Leaves Employee would be taking is

```
$totalleaves = $endDate - $startDate //It is not right way to take out the differece only For sake of Example shown it
```

which would give me total leaves `9` or `10` days

But If We See, These Leaves Are Divided in Two Different Months.
And i want to generate a Report and i want to see how many leaves employee has taken for specific month which is lets suppose last month `January`

it would be 4 days i suppose for below dates as below dates comes in date range and they belong to January.

```
28-1-2015
29-1-2015
30-1-2015
31-1-2015
```

so if i would like to have a result of array of every month leaves it would 
be like

```
array(
'January' => array(
 'TotalLeavesTaken' => 4
),
'February' => array(
'TotalLeavesTaken' => 6
)
);
```

I think thats the best i could explain..

Comment: How is startDate related to the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count days within a month from date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446321/count-days-within-a-month-from-date-range)

Comment: Why not only consider consider only the date's day. let's say if your date is 2015-2-3, consider only `3`, this will give you 3 as you asked. So if it is 2015-02-27, then you should grab only `27` and the current month, that will give 27 days of current month

Comment: you can get it simple using date('d');

Comment: @symbolicConstant
Thankyou sir for reply, But that is just an example, lets suppose i want to count last month dates what would i have to do then in same date range?

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adjusted after update in question**

Ok, now I have adjusted after your last update. Hope it is what you're looking for:

```
function getLeavesInPeriod($start, $end) {

    $date = new DateTime($start);
    $endDate = new DateTime($end);

    $leaves = array();

    while($date <= $endDate ) {
        $year = $date->format('Y');
        $month = $date->format('M');        

        if(!array_key_exists($year, $leaves))
            $leaves[$year] = array();
        if(!array_key_exists($month, $leaves[$year]))
            $leaves[$year][$month] = 0;

        $leaves[$year][$month]++;
        $date->modify("+1 day");
    }
    return $leaves;
}

$leaves = getLeavesInPeriod("2015-1-5", "2015-2-3");
print $leaves[2015]["Jan"]; //27
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks, Many Thanks.. That was what i was trying to implement from Yesterday..
Love your Work.. You r genius.. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understood your question correctly,

```
date('d', strtotime($endDate));
```

Comment: Thankyou sir for reply, sir, that was an example question.
I want to count dates/days in a date range for particular month.
e-g: in feburary total days would be 3, as in this date range on 3 days belongs to February and whole January dates would be counted 31 or 30 plus if we find for december then 20 or 21 days would be counted depending on dates of december matches the date range.

Sorry for my bad english..

Comment: @SizzlingCode: then you're looking for DateTime::diff, right? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Yes, but problem is how to count days in a particular month for a given date range.

Comment: @SizzlingCode: sorry, i don't understand what you need... Can you put more examples of start/endDate and what you want ot return in these examples? Put them into your question, please.

Comment: Sorry, My Bad, No. Date Diff will take the difference.. 
i meant count days in a month, I am not sure if its possible with date difference..

Comment: @SizzlingCode: if endDate will be 2015-2-18. What you want to return? If it will be 2015-3-6, what return than?

Comment: if `2015-2-18` is `end Date` and i want the `feburary` month days to be counted then i will get 18 days and if it is `start date` and i want same feburary month then i will get dates 28 - 18 = 10 days in counting and in leap year it would be 11 as 29-18 = 11..
Also updated my question.

Comment: @SINGHKD is answer is close to what i want but that counts all the dates in the date range i want to count only specific month dates..

Comment: @SizzlingCode: 18 days? Where you took 29? It should be startDate/endDate? PLease give me more examples or start/endDates and result, then we can find a solution. It will be nothing difficult, but I don't exactly know what you need to achieve :-(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @zaq178miami: question was updated due to comments above; the solution passed to original question quite well.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets try this

```
$month = strtotime(date('Y-m-01', time()));
$daysCount = (int)(time() - $month) / (24 * 3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you: i m using this to get days

```
$date_diff = $end_date - $start_date;
//difference of two  dates
```

This will return you number of days.Is just you want this or something else.Please confirm if it will help you.

```
$days_left = floor($date_diff / (60*60*24));// No. of days
```

Comment: Yes, i want something like this.. But it is getting all the days from startdate to end_date.
What i want is from specific month in that range..

Comment: yes it is possible,You could split your date and check if your months is 12 or what you want(define constant for that) and then put above code inside if statement.Please reply if it will help you.